# Foreground Push Notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

The push-notification forces the app to another screen without even the user clicking on the notification, whenever I send a notification using cloud messaging from firebase.

I want the user to first tap on the notification, which will then push to another screen. The code below is for the app running in the foreground, where I am facing the issue.

Ty in advance. It's for ANDROID*

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      final routeFromMessage = message.data['route'];
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeFromMessage);

      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel!.id,
              channel!.name,
              channel!.description,
              //      one that already exists in example app.
              icon: 'launch_background',
            ),
          ),
          payload: message.data['route'],
        );
      }
    });
```